# using Flex, place one div below another

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie and first time asking questions here.
Please how do I place the div PHOTO-GRID-CONTAINER below HEADER. I need the photo-grid container items below the header items. See my codes below

```
<div class='header-container'>
    <div class='header'>
    <div class='subscribe'>Subscribe &#9662;</div>
    <div class='logo'><img src='file:///C:/Users/lofty/Desktop/CODE%203/FLEX/awesome- 
     logo.svg'/></div>
    <div class='social'><img src='file:///C:/Users/lofty/Desktop/CODE%203/FLEX/social- 
     icons.svg'/></div>
    </div>

    <div class='photo-grid-container'>
      <div class='photo-grid'>
        <div class='photo-grid-item first-item'>
        <img src='images/three.svg'/></div>
        <div class='photo-grid-item mid-item'>
        <img src='images/two.svg'/></div>
        <div class='photo-grid-item last-item'>
        <img src='images/one.svg'/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>


.header-container {
  color: #5995DA;
  background-color: #D6E9FE;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.header {
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center; 
}
.photo-grid-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in `.header-container` add `flex-direction: column`. See [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for flexbox tips with positioning

```css
.header-container {
    color: #5995DA;
    background-color: #D6E9FE;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* here what I added in your code */
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
    width: 900px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items:center; 
}
.photo-grid-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class='header-container'>
        <div class='header'>
           <div class='subscribe'>Subscribe &#9662;</div>
           <div class='logo'>
                <img src='https://picsum.photos/201'/>
            </div>
           <div class='social'>
                <img src='https://picsum.photos/201'/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='photo-grid-container'>
           <div class='photo-grid'>
              <div class='photo-grid-item first-item'>
                 <img src='https://picsum.photos/200'/>
              </div>
              <div class='photo-grid-item mid-item'>
                 <img src='https://picsum.photos/200'/>
              </div>
              <div class='photo-grid-item last-item'>
                 <img src='https://picsum.photos/200'/>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put flex direction on class header container

```
 .header-container {
   color: #5995DA;
   background-color: #D6E9FE;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
 }
```

So you are telling the parent div that containers would be in columns.

Comment: this will mess up the rest of your html.  see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your very last `</div>` tag to just above `photo-grid-container`. Like so:

```css
.header-container {
  color: #5995DA;
  background-color: #D6E9FE;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header {
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border:solid 1px red;
}

.photo-grid-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border:solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<div class='header-container'>
  <div class='header'>
    <div class='subscribe'>Subscribe &#9662;</div>
    <div class='logo'><img src='file:///C:/Users/lofty/Desktop/CODE%203/FLEX/awesome- 
     logo.svg' /></div>
    <div class='social'><img src='file:///C:/Users/lofty/Desktop/CODE%203/FLEX/social- 
     icons.svg' /></div>
  </div>
 </div>

  <div class='photo-grid-container'>
    <div class='photo-grid'>
      <div class='photo-grid-item first-item'>
        <img src='images/three.svg' /></div>
      <div class='photo-grid-item mid-item'>
        <img src='images/two.svg' /></div>
      <div class='photo-grid-item last-item'>
        <img src='images/one.svg' /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```